# Show that $E[ N^T C N N^T]=0$ where $N \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a zero-mean Gaussian vector with covariance matrix $\Sigma$

Tags: matrices, probability-theory, gaussian

Let $N \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a zero-mean Gaussian vector with covariance matrix $\Sigma$.  I am trying to compute
\begin{align}
E[ N^T C N N^T]
\end{align}
where $C$ is $n \times n$ symetric positive-definite matrix.

**What I tried:**
In the scalar case, this is zero because we get  $CE[N^3]=0$.  I also tried a $2 \times 2$ example and it is zero there as well.

Comment: Hint: $N$ and $-N$ have the same distribution.

Comment: @StubbornAtom   Let me get this write you saying if I use your hint we get: $E[N^T CNN^T]=-E[N^T CNN^T]$, right?  This can only happen when $E[N^T CNN^T]=0$. Am I, correct?

Comment: Right$\color{white}.$